# Dailymotion api player, how to choose your own related video

Tags: dailymotion-api

I didn't see in the documentation if it's possible to define your own related video on the endscreen of a video with javascript SDK.

I see param 'endscreen-enable' to turn on/off related video on endscreen, but no param to choose my own related video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to choose your related videos in the end screen. As you say, you can only disable the related videos on end screen using `endscreen-enable` player parameter.